# How can I create AsyncTask of my getTotalIncomeAmount() which is an Integer type function in my IncomeDao class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room

I want to get total income amount from my Income table which have Amount table

```
 @ColumnInfo(name = "Amount")
    private int amount;
```

And in my IncomeDao I've

```
 @Query("SELECT SUM(amount) from income_table")
    Integer getTotalIncomeAmount();
```

And in my IncomeRepository I've

```
public Integer getTotalIncomeAmount()
    {

        return incomeDao.getTotalIncomeAmount();
    }
```

In my IncomeViewModel

```
public Integer getTotalIncomeAmount()
    {
        return incomeRepository.getTotalIncomeAmount();
    }
```

And I call this in my Main thread like this

```
totalIncome = incomeViewModel.getTotalIncomeAmount();
```

But it gives me the error that 'Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.'

I know this error can be remove by creating  `LiveData<Integer> getTotalIncomeAmount()`.
But I don't want to do this by `LiveData` because I've to observe it which is not good in my case.

I want someone to show me how to create `AsyncTask` of this method in my `IncomeRepository`class because I know this is the only way to get rid of this error.
I'm fairly new in programming.
As I created other `AsyncTask` like this in my `IncomeRepository`

```
private static class UpdateIncomeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Income, Void, Void>
    {
        private IncomeDao incomeDao;
        private UpdateIncomeAsyncTask(IncomeDao incomeDao)
        {
            this.incomeDao = incomeDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Income... incomes)
        {
            incomeDao.update(incomes[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I just need someone to complete `private static class TotalIncomeAmountAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`
for me. I tried very hard but I could succeed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code,

You will get amount in `doInBackgroud` method from database, after geting value you will get call in `onPostExecute` method. If you have global variable then you can directly set value in `doInBackgroud` method.

```html
private void getTotalIncomeAmount() {
        class TotalIncomeAmountAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
             
                Integer value = DatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppDatabase()
                        .taskDao()
                        .getTotalIncomeAmount();
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer value) {
                super.onPostExecute(value);
                //
            }
        }
        TotalIncomeAmountAsyncTask totalIncome = new TotalIncomeAmountAsyncTask();
        totalIncome.execute();
    }
```

Comment: where should I write this method..? and why this method is void? when I want an integer value in return.

Comment: You can write this method in class where you want to get that value, and there is many ways to get result value from `onPostExecute` you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575319/9792247

Comment: And should I change it to `private integer getTotalIncomeAmount()` ? because I want integer value in return..

Comment: No it's not possible in this case. You can define global variable for that, and direclty assign value to this global variable in `doInBackground` method in place of `Integer value`

Comment: `getAppDatabase()` this method gives me error that I'm not able to call it... It shows me to create this method in my Database

Comment: You've that method with another name that's why it's giving error. Check your `DatabaseClient` class where you've declare method and returns an instance of `appDatabase`. Use that method name in place.

Comment: I've these methods in my Database and my database name is ExpenseManagerDB
`private static ExpenseManagerDB INSTANCE;
    public abstract CategoryDao categoryDao();
    public abstract PaymentModeDao paymentModeDao();
    public abstract IncomeDao incomeDao();
    public abstract ExpenseDao expenseDao();`
which method I should call in that place?

Comment: You don't have that method. Refer this link to setup room database https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-room-database-example/

Comment: Give upvote or accept answer if it's solve your problem. So this will be also useful for others in future.

Comment: yes of course and if my question is valid also give vote